# JSON Recursion in PostgreSQL - Infinite Looping

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, recursive-query

I have the following JSON stored in PostgreSQL column (of jsonb type).

```
{
  "entity": "Book",
  "processes": [
       { "process": [
        { "processname": "Use",
          "option": "none",
          "processes": [
           { "process": [
           { "processname": "Lend",
            "option": "*",
            "processes": [
            { "process": [
              {
               "processname": "Borrow",
               "option": "none"
            }
        ]
    },
.......
```

I want to retrieve a list of all the processes together with their parent process and level. Something like this

```
Processname   Parent  Level
Use           {}        0 
Lend          Use       1
Borrow        Lend,Use  2
```

I have written the following code but it keeps on executing for a long time (infinite loop) without outputting any result.

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursion AS (
    SELECT  process -> 'processname' as processname, '{}'::jsonb[] as parents, 0 as lvl
    FROM   test3, jsonb_array_elements(j-> 'processes') processes, jsonb_array_elements(processes-> 'process') process


    UNION ALL
    select process -> 'processname' as processname, parents || '{}'::jsonb[], lvl+1
    FROM test3, jsonb_array_elements(j-> 'processes') processes, jsonb_array_elements(processes-> 'process') process
    JOIN recursion p on process -> 'processname' = p.processname
    WHERE not process -> 'processname' = any(parents)



)
SELECT *
FROM recursion;
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: As I can see the `parents` array is always empty so `not process -> 'processname' = any(parents)` is always `true`. Add `and lvl < 1000 /*just an example amount*/` to the second query and look to the result.

Comment: It returned a result however not the result I wanted. It returned the processnames at level 0 for 1000 times. I want to list all the processnames in the json once together with their parent names (if parents exist)